# Can't connect to the ETCD of Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, etcd

I've [accidentally drained/uncordoned all nodes in Kubernetes (even master)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544534/accidentally-drained-all-nodes-in-kubernetes-even-master-how-can-i-bring-my-k/62546194#62546194) and now I'm trying to bring it back by connecting to the ETCD and manually change some keys in there. I successfuly bashed into etcd container:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
8fbcb67da963        quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.3.10                "/usr/local/bin/etcd"    17 hours ago        Up 17 hours                             etcd1
a0d6426df02a        cd48205a40f0                               "kube-controller-man…"   17 hours ago        Up 17 hours                             k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-node1_kube-system_0441d7804a7366fd957f8b402008efe5_16
5fa8e47441a0        6bed756ced73                               "kube-scheduler --au…"   17 hours ago        Up 17 hours                             k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-node1_kube-system_6f33d7866b72ca1b13c79edd42fa8dc6_14
2c8e07cf499f        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 17 hours ago        Up 17 hours                             k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-node1_kube-system_6f33d7866b72ca1b13c79edd42fa8dc6_3
2ca43282ea1c        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 17 hours ago        Up 17 hours                             k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-node1_kube-system_0441d7804a7366fd957f8b402008efe5_3
9473644a3333        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 17 hours ago        Up 17 hours                             k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-node1_kube-system_93ff1a9840f77f8b2b924a85815e17fe_3
```

and then I run:

```
docker exec -it 8fbcb67da963 /bin/sh
```

and then I try to run the following:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints https://172.16.16.111:2379 --cacert /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem --key /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node1-key.pem --cert /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node1.pem get / --prefix=true -w json --debug
```

and here is the result I get:

```
ETCDCTL_CACERT=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem
ETCDCTL_CERT=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node1.pem
ETCDCTL_COMMAND_TIMEOUT=5s
ETCDCTL_DEBUG=true
ETCDCTL_DIAL_TIMEOUT=2s
ETCDCTL_DISCOVERY_SRV=
ETCDCTL_ENDPOINTS=[https://172.16.16.111:2379]
ETCDCTL_HEX=false
ETCDCTL_INSECURE_DISCOVERY=true
ETCDCTL_INSECURE_SKIP_TLS_VERIFY=false
ETCDCTL_INSECURE_TRANSPORT=true
ETCDCTL_KEEPALIVE_TIME=2s
ETCDCTL_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT=6s
ETCDCTL_KEY=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node1-key.pem
ETCDCTL_USER=
ETCDCTL_WRITE_OUT=json
INFO: 2020/06/24 15:44:07 ccBalancerWrapper: updating state and picker called by balancer: IDLE, 0xc420246c00
INFO: 2020/06/24 15:44:07 dialing to target with scheme: ""
INFO: 2020/06/24 15:44:07 could not get resolver for scheme: ""
INFO: 2020/06/24 15:44:07 balancerWrapper: is pickfirst: false
INFO: 2020/06/24 15:44:07 balancerWrapper: got update addr from Notify: [{172.16.16.111:2379 <nil>}]
INFO: 2020/06/24 15:44:07 ccBalancerWrapper: new subconn: [{172.16.16.111:2379 0  <nil>}]
INFO: 2020/06/24 15:44:07 balancerWrapper: handle subconn state change: 0xc4201708d0, CONNECTING
INFO: 2020/06/24 15:44:07 ccBalancerWrapper: updating state and picker called by balancer: CONNECTING, 0xc420246c00
Error: context deadline exceeded
```

Here is my etcd.env:

```
# Environment file for etcd v3.3.10
ETCD_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/etcd
ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=https://172.16.16.111:2379
ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS=https://172.16.16.111:2380
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE=existing
ETCD_METRICS=basic
ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=https://172.16.16.111:2379,https://127.0.0.1:2379
ETCD_ELECTION_TIMEOUT=5000
ETCD_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL=250
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN=k8s_etcd
ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=https://172.16.16.111:2380
ETCD_NAME=etcd1
ETCD_PROXY=off
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER=etcd1=https://172.16.16.111:2380,etcd2=https://172.16.16.112:2380,etcd3=https://172.16.16.113:2380
ETCD_AUTO_COMPACTION_RETENTION=8
ETCD_SNAPSHOT_COUNT=10000

# TLS settings
ETCD_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem
ETCD_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node1.pem
ETCD_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node1-key.pem
ETCD_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH=true

ETCD_PEER_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem
ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node1.pem
ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/member-node1-key.pem
ETCD_PEER_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH=True
```

**Update 1:**

Here is my kubeadm-config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 172.16.16.111
  bindPort: 6443
certificateKey: d73faece88f86e447eea3ca38f7b07e0a1f0bbb886567fee3b8cf8848b1bf8dd
nodeRegistration:
  name: node1
  taints: []
  criSocket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
clusterName: cluster.local
etcd:
  external:
      endpoints:
      - https://172.16.16.111:2379
      - https://172.16.16.112:2379
      - https://172.16.16.113:2379
      caFile: /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem
      certFile: /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-node1.pem
      keyFile: /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-node1-key.pem
dns:
  type: CoreDNS
  imageRepository: docker.io/coredns
  imageTag: 1.6.0
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  serviceSubnet: 10.233.0.0/18
  podSubnet: 10.233.64.0/18
kubernetesVersion: v1.16.6
controlPlaneEndpoint: 172.16.16.111:6443
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
imageRepository: gcr.io/google-containers
apiServer:
  extraArgs:
    anonymous-auth: "True"
    authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
    bind-address: 0.0.0.0
    insecure-port: "0"
    apiserver-count: "1"
    endpoint-reconciler-type: lease
    service-node-port-range: 30000-32767
    kubelet-preferred-address-types: "InternalDNS,InternalIP,Hostname,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP"
    profiling: "False"
    request-timeout: "1m0s"
    enable-aggregator-routing: "False"
    storage-backend: etcd3
    runtime-config: 
    allow-privileged: "true"
  extraVolumes:
  - name: usr-share-ca-certificates
    hostPath: /usr/share/ca-certificates
    mountPath: /usr/share/ca-certificates
    readOnly: true
  certSANs:
  - kubernetes
  - kubernetes.default
  - kubernetes.default.svc
  - kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
  - 10.233.0.1
  - localhost
  - 127.0.0.1
  - node1
  - lb-apiserver.kubernetes.local
  - 172.16.16.111
  - node1.cluster.local
  timeoutForControlPlane: 5m0s
controllerManager:
  extraArgs:
    node-monitor-grace-period: 40s
    node-monitor-period: 5s
    pod-eviction-timeout: 5m0s
    node-cidr-mask-size: "24"
    profiling: "False"
    terminated-pod-gc-threshold: "12500"
    bind-address: 0.0.0.0
    configure-cloud-routes: "false"
scheduler:
  extraArgs:
    bind-address: 0.0.0.0
  extraVolumes:
---
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
bindAddress: 0.0.0.0
clientConnection:
 acceptContentTypes: 
 burst: 10
 contentType: application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf
 kubeconfig: 
 qps: 5
clusterCIDR: 10.233.64.0/18
configSyncPeriod: 15m0s
conntrack:
 maxPerCore: 32768
 min: 131072
 tcpCloseWaitTimeout: 1h0m0s
 tcpEstablishedTimeout: 24h0m0s
enableProfiling: False
healthzBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10256
hostnameOverride: node1
iptables:
 masqueradeAll: False
 masqueradeBit: 14
 minSyncPeriod: 0s
 syncPeriod: 30s
ipvs:
 excludeCIDRs: []
 minSyncPeriod: 0s
 scheduler: rr
 syncPeriod: 30s
 strictARP: False
metricsBindAddress: 127.0.0.1:10249
mode: ipvs
nodePortAddresses: []
oomScoreAdj: -999
portRange: 
udpIdleTimeout: 250ms
---
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
clusterDNS:
- 169.254.25.10
```

**Update 2:**

Contents of /etc/kubernetes/manigests/kube-apiserver.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=172.16.16.111
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --anonymous-auth=True
    - --apiserver-count=1
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-aggregator-routing=False
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --endpoint-reconciler-type=lease
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ca.pem
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-node1.pem
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/node-node1-key.pem
    - --etcd-servers=https://172.16.16.111:2379,https://172.16.16.112:2379,https://172.16.16.113:2379
    - --insecure-port=0
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalDNS,InternalIP,Hostname,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP
    - --profiling=False
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.key
    - --request-timeout=1m0s
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --runtime-config=
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/sa.pub
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.233.0.0/18
    - --service-node-port-range=30000-32767
    - --storage-backend=etcd3
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.key
    image: gcr.io/google-containers/kube-apiserver:v1.16.6
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 172.16.16.111
        path: /healthz
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ca-certificates
      name: etc-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl
      name: etcd-certs-0
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etcd-certs-0
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      type: ""
    name: usr-share-ca-certificates
status: {}
```

I used kubespray to install the cluster.

How can I connect to the etcd? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how was the Kubernets and etcd installed ? used kubeadm?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I used Kubespray

Comment: try running the same command from the node directly without going into the etcd container

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I did. I'm getting the exact same result.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I asked this question because Rico in my linked question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544534/accidentally-drained-all-nodes-in-kubernetes-even-master-how-can-i-bring-my-k/62546194#62546194) suggested connecting to ETCD and manually examine/delete some of the node keys may solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `context deadline exceeded` generally happens because of

1. Using wrong certificates. You could be using peer certificates instead of client certificates. You need to check the Kubernetes API Server parameters which will tell you where are the client certificates located because Kubernetes API Server is a client to ETCD. Then you can use those same certificates in the `etcdctl` command from the node.
2. The etcd cluster is not operational anymore because peer members are down.

Comment: I've updated my answer and included the content of kubeadm-config.yaml file. It seems they are the same ones that I'm using in my command.

Comment: Can you share the content of /etc/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml from the master node

Comment: I just updated my question and added the contents of /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml

Comment: Are you able to run any other command using etcdctl such as snapshot save snapshotdb https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#built-in-snapshot

Comment: No it's the same. Is it because I have 3 endpoints and I just mentioned the first one? For some reasons the other two nodes were physically burned out!

Comment: Well then the etcd is cluster is not operational anymore because it has lost other 2 peers...it's recommended to take snapshot periodically to avoid these kind of scenario..Do you have any snapshot?

Comment: You're right. No, I'm f...ed then Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@Arghya Sadhu provided the correct explanation as to the why.

And while this may not work in the original situation of the OP, this problem occurs even on a healthy cluster when trying to reach `etcd` directly via `etcdctl` without any special options even inside its pod.

For people coming here having created their cluster via `kubeadm` and with default options, here is the correct full command to reach etcd from `kubectl`:

```
k exec -n kube-system etcd-<master_node> -- etcdctl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ser
ver.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key <etcd_subcommand>
```

Indeed, the certs are copied at cluster creation into the **etcd** node at this location for local access via `etcdctl`.